# Prepopulating HTML Radio selection using php

Tags: php, html, forms, radio-button

So based on if my database value is a 1 or 0 I want this enabled/disabled api settings page radio buttons to be prepopulated. Yet everything I have seen online simply is not working. Any ideas how to get this to work? Here is my snippit code on how I am doing my radio portion. Keep in mind when I select enable or disable and submit my form it does change the database value to a 1 or 0. I just can't get it to be selected when the page loads for my life :| ... Any help is appreciated! status is my variable set to a 1 or 0 by the way!

```
<form action="api_settings.php"  method="post">
<table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
  <tr>
    Status:<br />
    <input type="radio" name="status"  value="0" <?php if($status == 0){?> checked="checked"<?}?> />Disabled Remote Access<br />
    <input type="radio" name="status"  value="1" <?php if($status == 1){?> checked="checked"<?}?> />Enabled Remote Access<br />
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it's a problem with the PHP, I think the problem is that you don't have a `<td></td>` tag within your `<tr></tr>`.

Before: http://jsfiddle.net/efYZF/
After:  http://jsfiddle.net/efYZF/1/

Comment: You sir are my hero. Problem solved. Good game. I am surprised not having the <td></td> tad would cause that kind of bug but hey I will take it.